# Hi, I'm new to scala, I'm tryin to return a map(Map[String, USER]) from a function but got the type mismatch error

Tags: scala

Here is my userRepository trait

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

trait userRepository {
  def addUser(id: String, user:USER):Map[String,USER]
  def removeUser(id: String):Map[String,USER]
  def getUser(id: String):Map[String,USER]
}
```

Here is my userRepositoryImpl class

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

class userRepositoryImpl extends userRepository {
  val userMap = Map.empty[String,USER]

  override def addUser(id: String, user: USER): Map[String,USER] = {
    userMap.put(id, user)
  }

  override def removeUser(id: String): Map[String,USER] = {
      userMap.remove(id)
    }

  override def getUser(id: String): Map[String,USER] = {
    userMap.find(_._2.id == id)
  }
}
```

Here is my USER class

```
case class USER(id: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, address: String, gender: String)
```

Eorro

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Option[USER]
 required: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,USER]
    userMap.put(id, user)
```

why I'm getting this error? can any buddy explain the reason?

Comment: what response does your client get from Elasticsearch?

Comment: co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport$RequestFuture@49c6c24f[Not completed]

Comment: If you check the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#put(key:K,value:V):Option[V]), `put` returns the optional previous value for the key, if existed, else `None`. `remove` will remove the `key -> value` pair returning the optional previous value, and `find` will return the `key -> value` pair if condition is met.

Comment: BTW, please don't edit the previous question to make it a new one. Do ask another question.

Comment: Thank you for your response , actually I'm new to SO so they don't allow me to post more question , so, that's i edit the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you,
It is resolved by returning the "userMap".

e.g

```
  override def removeUser(id: String): Map[String, USER] = {
    userMap.remove(id)
    userMap
  }
```

this is the mismatch error